# Is there any other way to create 'parametrized' class?

Tags: python, class, inheritance

Let's say I have such class:

```py
class A(object):
    PREFIX = "1"
    text = "%s) some text" % PREFIX
```

Now I want to create an ancestor with changed PREFIX

```py
class B(A):
    PREFIX = "2"
    other_field = "other text"
```

But that doesn't work as I want it to

```py
a = A()
b = B()
print(a.text)  # 1) some text
print(b.text)  # 1) some text
```

And I know why. Okay, I figured out how to make work...

```py
# And now for something (not really) completely different...

def factory(prefix):
    class Meta(object):
        text = "%s) some text" % prefix
    return Meta

A = factory(prefix="1")

class B(factory(prefix="2")):
    other_field = "other text"

a = A()
b = B()

print(a.text)  #1) some text
print(b.text)  #2) some text
```

...but that looks kinda ugly to me. 
Is there any better way to do such thing? Or am I just wrong about the ugliness?

I've tried to play with mixins, but with no luck.

*NOTE: For some reason I can't initialize PREFIX in constructor, I just NEED to parametrize attribute initialization in class definition*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could achieve something similar with descriptors (`__get__` method - [doc](https://docs.python.org/3.6/howto/descriptor.html)):

```
class prefixed_text:
    def __init__(self, s):
        self.s = s

    def __get__(self, obj, _type=None):
        return self.s.format(_type.PREFIX)

class A:
    PREFIX = "1"
    text = prefixed_text("{}) some text")

class B(A):
    PREFIX = "2"

#classes:
print(A.text)
print(B.text)

#instances:
print(A().text)
print(B().text)
```

Prints:

```
1) some text
2) some text
1) some text
2) some text
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!
I think it worth noting that for python2 `prefixed_text` should be a new style class.

Answer (score 0):

You can make the attribute `text` a property (which is an easy way to make descriptors):

```
class A(object):
    PREFIX = "1"
    @property
    def text(self):
        return "%s) some text" % self.PREFIX


class B(A):
    PREFIX = "2"
    other_field = "other text"


a = A()
b = B()
print(a.text)  # -> 1) some text
print(b.text)  # -> 2) some text
```